# count the frequency, how to have zero frequencies?

Tags: r

I wish to know the frequencies that occurred 0. Is there any simple way for that?

```
mydf <-data.frame(v1= c("a","b","b","a","b"), v2 =c("l1", "l2","l1","l1","l2"))
```

I use this one to see the frequencies of `v1` and `v2`

```
library(plyr)
count(mydf, c('v1','v2'))
```

It gives me the following outcome.

```
  v1 v2 freq
1  a l1    2
2  b l1    1
3  b l2    2
```

I wish to have zeros in my output. For instance combination of `a` and `l2` never occurred. How can I have the following output?

```
  v1 v2 freq
1  a l1    2
2  b l1    1
3  b l2    2
4  a l2    0
```

Comment: as.data.frame(table(mydf$v1, mydf$v2))

Comment: Simple hack: You can use expand.grid to generate a data frame with  all the combinations of factor levels.  Then you can just join that with the result you already have.

Comment: you can use `dplyr` package and do sth like `this library(dplyr)
nf %>% group_by(v1, v2) %>% summarise(no = n())` but it looses the line where the `Freq == 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table(mydf$v1, mydf$v2)

    l1 l2
  a  2  0
  b  1  2

as.data.frame(table(mydf$v1, mydf$v2))
   Var1 Var2 Freq
1    a   l1    2
2    b   l1    1
3    a   l2    0
4    b   l2    2
```